# The Riddle - I Could be Seen in Many Places

Tags: riddle, word

> In whole, you may see me in the competition, or on the street.
>
> Remove my front part, you may see me in the body, or on the lawn.
>
> Remove my rear part, you may see me in the prison, or in the grocery.
>
> Remove my middle part, you may see me in the sea, or on the stage.
>
> Remove my middle part again, you may see me in the baseball game, or in the university.

Who/What am I?

**Hint 1:**

> Chances to see in places(based on my thoughts :P):
>
>   **competition**: **LOW** to **HIGH**, positive correlate to competition schedule.
>   **street**: **LOW**, but vary in cities or countries.
>
>   **body**: **VERY HIGH**.
>   **lawn**: **MEDIUM**.
>
>   **prison**: **HIGH**.
>   **grocery**: **LOW**, but vary in locations.
>
>   **sea**: **MEDIUM**.
>   **stage**: **MEDIUM**.
>
>   **baseball game**: **LOW to MEDIUM**.
>   **university**: **HIGH**.

**Hint 2:**

> The answer could be a noun or an adjective. Also the answer has 2 main meanings which are almost on the contrary.

Comment: You're an [inspirational fellow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89613/5373), Conifers :-)

Comment: :D same to you~~~

Comment: Any chance for a Hint 2?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Keep going~! :P

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Hint 2 released, here you go :)

Comment: Nice, thanks. Does “could be a noun or an adjective” mean the answer could be used as either or are those two separate options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll see where this goes...

My guess is:

> **BADASS**

In whole, you may see me in the competition, or on the street.

> You could be a **BADASS** competitor or a gangster

Remove my front part, you may see me in the body, or on the lawn.

> You have an **ASS** and a donkey could be on the lawn

Remove my rear part, you may see me in the prison, or in the grocery.

> **BAD** people go to prison and they could rob grocery stores?

Remove my middle part, you may see me in the sea, or on the stage.

> **BA**DA**SS** = **BASS** like a sea bass or a bass guitar

Remove my middle part again, you may see me in the baseball game, or in the university.

> **B**ADAS**S** = **BS** like a bachelor of science or blown save in baseball

Answer to clue #2

> Badass in a noun and adjective. A badass is someone who is good or you could have a literal bad ass (flat/lumpy) XD

Comment: I'm hoping you're right on this. For the lawn part, maybe it refers to people sitting down (because I don't imagine donkeys having a medium probability of being present).

Comment: Yes, great job! The grocery may have more "expired" or "defective" products compared to the supermarket, and more the remote is the chance may be higher. @JS1 the donkeys and sitting down both counts on the prob., so I give it MEDIUM :P Anyway just my thoughts...(I know that it may vary in different environments or cultures)

Answer (score 8):

I found something that sort of fits:

In whole, you may see me in the competition, or on the street.

> **BASKETBALLS** (basketball competition, street ball)

Remove my front part, you may see me in the body, or on the lawn.

> basket**BALLS** (balls of feet, Wimbledon or lawn bowling)

Remove my rear part, you may see me in the prison, or in the grocery.

> **BASKET**balls (laundry baskets, grocery baskets)

Remove my middle part, you may see me in the sea, or on the stage.

> **BAS**ketball**S** (**BASS**) (sea bass, bass guitar)

Remove my middle part again, you may see me in the baseball game, or in the university.

> **B**asketball**S** (**BS**) (Blown Save or Bs as in Balls/Strikes, Bs as in B grades)

Comment: Nice try and a bit close to the answer :P

Comment: (Balls of feet?) :)

Comment: @Chowzen If you look at the edit history of my answer, you will see I had something else there before, lol.

Comment: It's time to suggest SE developer to develop **content grading system** could be applied on questions :D

Answer (score 6):

My guess is:

> **MISSTART**

In whole, you may see me in the competition, or on the street.

> A race that starts prematurely or a car that needs a jump start

Remove my front part, you may see me in the body, or on the lawn.

> ART (MISST**ART**) A tattoo or statue

Remove my rear part, you may see me in the prison, or in the grocery.

> MISS (**MISS**TART) You may miss someone in prison or something at the shops

Remove my middle part, you may see me in the sea, or on the stage.

> STAR (MIS**STAR**T) startfish or a celebrity

Remove my middle part again, you may see me in the baseball game, or in the university.

> MIT (**MI**SSTAR**T**) a glove or institute

Comment: Nice try~ But "Remove my middle part" your answer should be MIST not STAR :D

Comment: @Conifers Aww got you, back to the drawing board.

Comment: rot13(zvfg, gur frn oybjf ybgf bs zvfg va gur zbeavat naq zvfg vf nyfb hfrq nf n fgntr cebc, sebz cynlf gb pbapregf)