# From Art to Offices

Tags: riddle, word

> I may be seen (though maybe that's not the right word) in a piece of art.
>   Remove my first, and I become a cheery greeting.
>   Remove my last, I may go to prison or an office computer.
>   Remove my middle, I'm in the office at the top.

What am I?

Comment: Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89611/5373) although the solution is different.

Comment: Is it possible that you have first and last reversed?

Comment: @Gareth Erm. Damn. Yes. Sorry for the muckup :-(

Comment: No apology needed; to err is human.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> a CELLO.

I may be seen (though maybe that's not the right word) in a piece of art.

> In, say, a symphony, but hearing is more the point than seeing.

Remove my first, and I become a cheery greeting.

> 'Ello!

Remove my last, I may go to prison or an office computer.

> A prison cell, or a cell in a spreadsheet.

Remove my middle, I'm in the office at the top.

> Then you're the CEO. (Though the LL isn't *exactly* in the middle...)

[EDITED to add:] The question originally had an error in it; since it's been fixed I've removed the bits of the answer relating to that.

Comment: My apologies for the ninja-ing, then!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ninjas are allowed here.

Comment: [I deleted a couple of comments that don't make sense now that the OP has been fixed.]