# I'm made of obsolete parts

Tags: riddle, word

> In whole, I describe a drink or a relationship.
>   Remove my front, and I become an obsolete part of a device.
>   Remove my end, and I become another obsolete part of the same device.
>   Remove my middle, and I am an endangered species.
>   Remove my middle again, and I am something that mankind is trying to make obsolete.

What am I?

<sub>* Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89611) and [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89613).</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution to this sweet riddle may be

> **cordial** - a non-carbonated drink and warm relations.

Remove my first,  I'm an obsolete part of a device. Remove my last, I'm an obsolete part of the same device.

> cord and dial - both obsolete for today's phone.

Remove my middle, and I am an endangered species.

> coral - a number of species of coral are endangered.

Remove my middle again, and I am something that mankind is trying to make obsolete.

> coal - mankind is trying to cut out coal burning.

Comment: That's awesome.  Are you also an NYT crossword hero?