# Used to Stop a Fight?

Tags: riddle, word

> In whole, you may see me on a farm or on The Moon.
>
> Remove my rear part, you may see me in a prison or in the supermarket.
>
> Remove my middle part, you may see me on my whole or on your head.
>
> Remove my middle part again, you may see me on a ship or on a stage.
>
> Remove my front part, you may see me in the previous word or on the street.
>
> Remove my front part again, you may see me on a river or in the theatre.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Thanks to [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89611/the-riddle-i-could-be-seen-in-many-places) for the inspiration.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In whole, you may see me on a farm or on The Moon.

> **barrow** - a wheelbarrow or a lunar crater  located near the northern limb of the Moon.

Remove my rear part, you may see me in a prison or in the supermarket.

> bar - prison cell bars or candy/snack bars.

Remove my middle part, you may see me on my whole or on your head.

> brow - the front of a barrow or the forehead.

Remove my middle part again, you may see me on a ship or on a stage.

> bow - the front of a ship, or an actor bending after a performance.

Remove my front part, you may see me in the previous word or on the street.

> arrow - found in an archery bow, or a street direction arrow.

Remove my front part again, you may see me on a river or in the theatre.

> row - see someone row on a river, or a row of seats in a theatre.

Title: Used to Stop a Fight?

> bar (prevent) and row (a fight)

Answer (score 1):

This one got a few clues in, but is obviously not correct:

> Cow

In whole, you may see me on a farm or on The Moon.

> Cows are seen on farms, and "the cow jumped over the moon"

Remove my rear part, you may see me in a prison or in the supermarket.

> CO stands for "Corrections Officer", which is a prison guard.  Some supermarkets are CO-OPs...

...and that's as far as I got before realizing that word was too short to do all of the clues.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this differently, and came up with one, one-word answer:

> Ship (or boat)

In whole, you may see me on a farm or on The Moon.

> farms ship goods; spaceship

Remove my rear part, you may see me in a prison or in the supermarket.

> Prisoners tried (succeeded?) to escape from Alcatraz in a boat by removing the rear wall of their cell; supermarkets have a gravy boat.

Remove my middle part, you may see me on my whole or on your head.

> The Hull is a homophone for whole; Seafood restaurant employees often wear a boat hat, with the middle part out for their head.

Remove my middle part again, you may see me on a ship or on a stage.

> A big ship uses little ships as tender and/or emergency; stages will often use just, say, the front part of a ship.

Remove my front part, you may see me in the previous word or on the street.

> Space-ships, often are launched from rockets that are removed during launch; DC, Pittsburgh, Disney World, and other places do car-boat tours.

Remove my front part again, you may see me on a river or in the theatre.

> A car ferry often looks like it has no front part; I saw "Titanic" in the theatre.

Lastly, the title:

> The US Navy has parked ships in-between two sides to stop them from fighting.